# 6th catalogue of orbits of visual binary stars

Tags: binary-star

I wanted to download or access the US navy catalog " the sixth catalog of orbits of visual binaries". I have already tried USNO web site and vizier. but I couldn't see them there. The link was dead for me; on www.usno.navy.mil, I reached the page but could not open the link. 
Is there any other site with downloadable or accessible data on the above-mentioned catalog available?

Comment: I fear this has been caught up in the long-running upgrade of servers at USNO. In the sidebar is a message: "The USNO websites aa.usno.navy.mil, ad.usno.navy.mil, aristarchus.usno.navy.mil, maia.usno.navy.mil, rorf.usno.navy.mil, and toshi.usno.navy.mil are undergoing modernization efforts.  The expected completion of the work and the estimated return of service is Summer 2020.". The catalog appears to be on `ad.usno.navy.mil` so is affected by this. Best bet is to try and find a mirror, maybe [at GSU](http://www.astro.gsu.edu/wds/orb6/)

Comment: I have this (https://vizier.u-strasbg.fr/viz-bin/VizieR-4)  here I got masses. is there any way to find the semimajor axis and eccentricity using this data. I have already tried (https://bdb.insan.ru) by typing IDs of each stars but again dead end.